# Google Charts setting the side to show only

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[image]

The above image is a Google Chart I made up. I would like to control the values at the side so it only shows `0 200 400 600` instead of `0 150 300 450 600`.

Ive looked over the google documentation and can't quite figure out what I should be looking for.

Comment: Can we see your code -- it'd really help.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `vAxis.ticks` option:

```
vAxis: {
    ticks: [0, 200, 400, 600]
}
```